# Justify the differentiation in Durrett's investment problem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve the Exercise 2.4.3.(ii) of the Durrett's book, 5th edition. Here, $V_{i}\geq0$ is a random variable over the measure space $\Omega$ with $EV_{i}^{2}<\infty$ and $EV_{i}^{-2}<\infty$.

Indeed, what I want to show is that the function $c(p):= E(\log (ap +(1-p)V_{i}))$ is concave using the theorem A.5.1 in the same book, which states that

[image]

Here, the condition (i), (ii) are satisfied by $c(p)$; for (i), I just divide $\Omega$ with two parts, where $\log (ap +(1-p)V_{i}) < 0$ and $\log (ap +(1-p)V_{i})\geq 0$, and then use $-\log x < 1/x^{2}$ or $\log x <x$ to show (i). (ii) is clear. However, I don't know how to show that $c(p)$ satisfy conditions (iii) and (iv). Do you have any idea for showing this?

Comment: Try to use the other theorem after this one. The other one is based completely on DCT.

Comment: @Mason Thank you! I will try to use Theorem A.5.3. instead!